# What if a point in $[a,b]$ does not lie in the domain of $f(x)$ while applying IVT

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, roots

I came across the function $f(x)=x^3\ln(\sin x)$. I tried applying IVT in the interval $\left[-\frac{5 \pi}{4},-\pi\right) \cup\left(0, \frac{3 \pi}{4}\right]$.
Now we see that
$$\begin{aligned}
f\left(-\frac{5 \pi}{4}\right) &=\frac{125 \pi^{3}}{128} \ln 2>0 \\
f\left(\frac{3 \pi}{4}\right) &=\frac{-27 \pi^{3}}{128} \ln 2<0
\end{aligned}$$
So $\exists$ at least one $c$ such that $f(c)=0$. It is also evident that $c=\frac{\pi}{2}$.
But if we observe there are two points at which $f$ is discontinuous viz $x=0,-\pi$. Is still IVT applicable?

Comment: No. The domain  has to be an interval for IVT.

Comment: The hypothesis of the intermediate value theorem is that the function be continuous on the entire interval; not being defined certainly prevents the function from being continuous.